# In C++ the fgets() function is not working

Tags: c++, fgets

why is fgets function not working?
error: C++ argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int indis = 0;
    char *g, firma[50];

    cout << "firma adı giriniz: ";

    fgets(firma, 50, g);

    g = firma;

    while (g[indis] != NULL) {
        cout << g[indis];
        indis++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: [`fgets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) takes a `FILE*` as third argument, not `char*`.

Comment: how about using gets(), not fgets()? It did not work either.

Comment: Programming by guessing will never work. _Think_ about what you are trying to do, then _study_ the documentation to find out how to do it.

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll how about *not* using `gets` That function is so vile and evil it was ripped from the standard library, not to return... *ever*. Use a function that lets you specify target size. i.e. `fgets`, and just learn to use it properly.

Comment: You cannot use functions at random and expect them to work, and `gets` got removed in modern C++. Please explain what you want to do rather than what you have tried.

Comment: I am trying to write a string by using pointers and arrays. Thay's all. In the book I study, the original code has gets(firma); instead of fgets(firma,50, g);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using it wrong.

`fgets` is for reading from a file (or stream).

You have no file (or stream).

**Did you perhaps mean `fgets(firma, 50, stdin);`?**

Consult some documentation for the functions that you use.

Comment: Cannot tell you how to fix it without you telling us what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to write a string by using pointers and arrays. Thay's all. The original code has gets(firma); instead of fgets(firma,50, g);

Comment: Where did you read that you should use `fgets(firma, 50, g)`? Which learning resource led you to that decision?

Comment: Yes the solution is fgets(firma, 50, stdin); thank you @Asteroids With Wings